# What is the best method to setup a new GAE project in Eclipse with Gradle Build

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gradle, initialization

What is the best method to setup a new GAE Eclipse project with Gradle?

Answer (score 1):

The fastest / most efficient method is:

1.) Download Eclipse, and Install Google Cloud Tools in Eclipse

- https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/quickstart
- Create new App Engine project
- Right click Project Name -> New -> Google App Engine...

2.) Install gradle

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html
- Install Gradle Plugin for Eclipse
- https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship

3.) Create a new GAE Project in the [GAE console](https://console.cloud.google.com/)

4.) Configure Eclipse project for Gradle

- Open Terminal on Mac or Command in windows
- change directory to root of GAE/Eclipse project
- run command:
- gradle init --type java-library;
- Close, reopen eclipse or ...
- in Eclipse right-click on project name / F5 Refresh
- IMPORTANT - Right click on the project name -> Configure -> Add Gradle Nature

5.) Add the gradle.build file...

- From Eclipse, create a new gradle.build file in the root of the project
- See example build.gradle here:
- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/using-gradle

6.) From Eclipse right click on the project name,

- Gradle -> "Refresh Gradle Project"
- (if Gradle is missing, make sure you've added Gradle nature from Step 5).

7.) Build project from Gradle using development environment,

- From the Terminal or command line.. from the root of the project) run command:
- gradle appengineRun

Other helpful links:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/using-gradle